# How to implement function to pointer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    //Declare block as property

    @property (nonatomic, strong) void (^dataBlock)(BOOL success);

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void) myMethod1:(void (^)(BOOL success))response {

        //Here data block holds the reference to response block

        _dataBlock = response;    
    }

    - (void) myMethod2 {

        //Check for _dataBlock and invoke it.

        if (_dataBlock) {    
            _dataBlock(YES);   
        }    
    }

   - (IBAction) buttonClick {

     //Call for myMethod1 and call back block is invoked in myMethod2

        [self myMethod1:^(BOOL success) { 

            if (success) {   
                NSLog(@"Im Done");   
            }    

        }];
   }
   @end
```

Above sample is my code in Objective-C

- Callback Block of "myMethod1"(response) is having reference/stored to "dataBlock" Property.
- then invoke "dataBlock" from "myMethod2".
- since "datablock" have reference to"myMethod1" block named "response", i'll be getting call back in "myMethod1", please look at the code snippet  (similar to function to pointer).
- same thing i want to implement in swift. I have tried implementing this in swift using closures, but not getting it.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not, unless it's on a Jailbroken device.

Apple does not let 3rd party apps alter the core behavior of the phone.

Now you **could** put the phone in a Faraday cage and put antennas on the inside and outside, and disconnect them when you wanted to block calls.

Comment: Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you sort of can, but not really programmatically from iOS. If the BLE device implements the HID profile then you can simulate a double click on the lock button which would dismiss the call. I have done that, but it is a bit of a clunky solution.

Comment: Thanks, Can you share a solution, if possible.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/Hut1_12v2.pdf Consumer Page (0x0C), Usage ID 0x30